# Visual Studio 2010 Pro includes LightSwitch. How?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I see the VS2010 Pro [includes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvpartneringwithmsft/thread/61f54bfa-41ae-4ea1-a871-d98127643c1f) LightSwitch.  But from the LightSwitch [website](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) only has links to download the 30 day demo (which can be extended by 60 days with a registration).

I don't have a MSDN subscription.  So how do I add this to my VS2010 Pro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though it not explicitly documented, seems like you can download "full" version of LightSwitch for VS 2010 only if you have MSDN subscription or any of following levels:

> Developer AA; VS Pro with MSDN (Retail); VS Premium with MSDN (MPN);
>   BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with
>   MSDN (VL); VS Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (Retail); VS
>   Ultimate with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN); MSDN AA
>   Institution; VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE);