# Is VS LightSwitch free if you own VS 2010 Pro?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010 Pro includes LightSwitch. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126064/visual-studio-2010-pro-includes-lightswitch-how)

Heading says it all really.  I would like to use LS for a reporting/simple management app I have to write, but I doubt I'll be able to get a license for a singe bit of development.  I've heard some people say LightSwitch comes with VS2010 Pro, but as I already had the beta installed before I got 2010, I'm not really sure where I stand!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126064/visual-studio-2010-pro-includes-lightswitch-how

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any information if Lightswitch is shipped with VS2010 prof (don't think so) as far as I can read my MSDN-Download description:

> Available to Levels: Developer AA; VS Pro with MSDN (Retail); VS Premium with MSDN (MPN); BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (VL); VS Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN); MSDN AA Institution; VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE);

you will get it when you have at least a VS Pro with MSDN subsrciption .. maybe this heps as well